# Pattern Matching on Generic Trait's Parameterized Type

Tags: scala

Given the following trait:

`trait Foo[_ <: Product] {}`

How can I pattern match on Foo's generic type?

In other words, is there a way to get at `Foo`'s `_` without using run-time reflection?

Comment: I doubt you could get that information even at runtime. Most probably that info is totally erased by that time.

Comment: so, is my above code not `idiomatic`? Is there a common, idiomatic pattern for this approach?

Comment: Well, it is not clear for me what you want to achieve. Maybe with `ClassTag`s or `Class` objects you can save the type information partially, but in that case I would not use existential type (`_`) as a type parameter, but a named one (`T` for example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pattern matching on generic type in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285235/pattern-matching-on-generic-type-in-scala)

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388302/pattern-matching-on-listt-and-sett-in-scala-vs-haskell-effects-of-type-era?rq=1

Comment: Yet another 5(!) year old related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `_` as a type parameter is to specify that the type is *unknown*.

Comment: I'm not sure this really qualifies as an answer.  This seems more like a comment to me.  Things like this might garner downvotes so you should consider switching it...

Comment: Ok, the **answer** is "no, there is no way". Is that better? :)

Comment: Yes it is possible.  See answer that I reluctantly posted (because it's a duplicate).

Comment: @cmbaxter: your answer is about a different question. Try `val fooBar: Foo[_ <: Product] = new Foo[Bar]{}; checkType(foo)`

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, and I still think it's a duplicate as noted by my comment, but wanted to show how you can do it anyway.  Credit to om-nom-nom for the original answer:

```
  trait Foo[_ <: Product]

  case class Bar(i:Int)
  case class Baz(s:String)  

  val fooBar = new Foo[Bar]{}
  val fooBaz = new Foo[Baz]{}

  checkType(fooBar)
  checkType(fooBaz)

  def checkType[T <: Product : TypeTag](foo:Foo[T]){
    foo match{
      case f if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Bar] => println("its a bar")
      case f if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Baz] => println("its a baz")
    }
  }
```

Comment: But `TypeTag`'s depend on run-time, not compile-time?

Comment: Both. It assures at compile time that a type tag is present for all `Foo`s supplied to `checkType`. Then at runtime the type tag makes what is usually erased info available.

Comment: How does Haskell handle this situation?

Comment: No clue. I'm not a Haskell guy.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, Haskell does not have subtyping in the first place. There are existential types, but you simply *cannot* extract the concrete type hidden inside an existential. You can only use typeclass methods, if there are any typeclass bounds on the existential.