# Scala: How can I match only the first two elements of an arbitrary List

Tags: list, scala, generics, pattern-matching, match

I'm attempting to match a lists first two elements, however, it wont accept lists of arbitrary length. The below code fails.

```
  def demoCases() = {
    def actor1 = new Actor[Employee] {}
    def actor2 = new Actor[Employee] {}
    def actor3 = new Actor[Animal] {}

    var actors = List(actor1, actor2, actor3);
    println();
    actors match {
      case (_: Employee) :: (_: Employee) :: tail
        => {println("nice 2  employees to start with ")};

      case Nil
        => {println("no match")}
    }
```

The exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: List(.....)
```

How can i specify that only the two elements *first* of the list need to match this expression?

Comment: you don't need { } after a `=>`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `case Nil` by `case _ => println("no match")`. `_` as a pattern means "match anything". But note that your first case requires that the first two elements of the list are `Employee`s, not `Actor`s.

Comment: The original goal is to match on the generic type (i.e. match employee,employee but not employee,animal).  Is that possible ? Its appearing not to be possible to match on generic types.  It appears that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056645/how-to-pattern-match-on-generic-type-in-scala has a more apropos solution.

Comment: actuallly, looking further, it appears my original intent, which is to match by the generic type, might not be possible at all ?

Comment: Yes, it's impossible in general. There are workarounds if you control the definition of `Actor`, as mentioned in the question you linked.

Answer (score 1):

The following does not work thanks to type-erasure (pointed out by Alexey Romanov)

```
case (_: Actor[Employee]) :: (_: Actor[Employee]) :: tail
```

Therefore I cannot think of any way to do what you want without restructuring the code.  For example if you made `Employee` a member of `Actor` somehow, and made `Actor` a case class, you could do

```
case Actor(_: Employee) :: Actor(_: Employee) :: tail
```

Comment: This won't work as desired thanks to type erasure. It'll only check that elements are `Actor[_]`, not `Actor[Employee]`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks for the feedback.  this is a tempting and instructive answer (hence the upvote), but not the precise solution.