# Explanation of List[_] in pattern matching used in flatten function

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, flatmap, partial-functions

I am new to scala and I can not understand the following function

```
val L = List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8)))       

def flatten(l: List[Any]): List[Any] =  l flatMap {
    case ms:List[_] => flatten(ms)
    case l => List(l)
}                                         

flatten(L)                      // res2: List[Any] = List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
```

In particular I do not understand the combination of `flatMap` and pattern matching and also the meaning of the first case `ms:List[_]`

Can someone explain that and maybe provide a simpler example to clarify the concept?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### `map` and `flatMap`

First of all `flatMap` is a [higher-order](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html) function.

`map` is also a higher order function which will convert a `List` to a new `List` by applying a function on all elements of that `List`. For example if you have

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
```

you can `map` it to a new list by using

```
val doubled = l.map(_ * 2)         // List(2,4,6)
```

So what is `flatMap`? `flatMap` is useful when your function gets an `Int` but returns a `List[Int]`. In this case if you pass this function to `map` what you get will be a `List[List[Int]]` but sometimes you want to get a `List[Int]` instead.

What you can do is to use `flatMap` instead. Mathematically it is equivalent to first `map` and then `flatten` the result but in action it could be the `flatten` function which is defined based on `flatMap` not the other way around.

Technical details aside, `flatten` means that if you have a `List[List[List...[Int]]]`, if you `flatten` it, you will get a `List[Int]`.

When we look at

```
def flatten(l: List[Any]): List[Any] =  l flatMap {
    case ms:List[_] => flatten(ms)
    case l => List(l)
}
```

we first need to know what does this mean. We already know that we have to pass a function to `flatMap`. In this case the function we are passing is

```
{
    case ms:List[_] => flatten(ms)
    case l => List(l)
}
```

which at first does not seem like a function but it is! It is actually a [partial function](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction) which you can consider as a function with some nuances!

### What is a partial function?

We could achieve (almost) the same result with:

```
def flatten(l: List[Any]): List[Any] =  l flatMap { _ match {
        case ms:List[_] => flatten(ms)
        case l => List(l)
    }   
}
```

The difference between an ordinary function and a partial function is that partial functions may be undefined for some specific inputs. So the compiler will automatically generate a partial function from a body which starts with `case` keyword (It's not that simple but for the sake of simplicity I skip the details here).

### Pattern matching by *Type*

A pattern like `ms:List[_]` is called a *type pattern*. It means that the type of `ms` will be checked in runtime against the `List[_]`. `_` is a wild card and means any type so `ms:List[_]` literally means a `List` of any type (Due to type erasure you can not use a pattern like `ms:List[Int]`, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete) thread for more info).

So the whole pattern match on this code snippets means that

- If `ms` is a list the result will be `flatten(ms)`, other wise the result will be `List(l)`.

The `flatten` function defined like this is recursive function which unwraps the lists and do this until there is no more list, then it will wrap the result again in a `List`! This way `List[List[List.......[_]]]` will be converted to `List[_]`.

An additional example for type-patterns:

```
def hello(o: Any) = o match {
    case _:Int => "Hi, I am an Int and I'm proud of it!"
    case _:List[_] => "I have many things to tell you! I am a list after all!"
    case b:Boolean => s"I'm simply a flag and my value is $b"
    case _ => "I'm everything else you can imagine :D"
}
```

### Disambiguation

By the way *partial function* is totally different from [*partially applied function*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/glossary/#partially-applied-function) and partial application!

The concept of partial function in Scala is the same as [partial function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) in mathematics: A function which may be undefined for some of the values of its [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function).