# Decide Type Parameter on runtime in Scala

Tags: scala, type-parameter

For example I have code looks like this:

```
class Parent
class Child1 extends Parent
class Child2 extends Parent

class Foo {

  def retrieve(arg: String): List[Parent] = {
    arg match {
      case "Child1" => get[Child1]()
      case "Child2" => get[Child2]()
    }
  }

  def get[T: Manifest](): List[T] = ...

}
```

In the `retrieve` method, I want to simplify the code into one `get` method call only like this:

```
  def retrieve(arg: String): List[Parent] = {
    val t = arg match {
      case "Child1" => ?
      case "Child2" => ?
    }

    get[t]()
  }
```

Is it possible to achieve this in scala?

**UPDATE:**

I tried the solution from the answer here but I got a problem, it doesn't work with overloaded `get` method, for example:

```
def get[T: Manifest](x: String): List[T] = ...

def get[T: Manifest, U: Manifest](x: String): List[(T, U)] = ...
```

For example, in the `retrieve`:

```
val t = arg match {
  case "Child1" => manifest[Child1]
  case "Child2" => manifest[Child2]
}

get("test")(t)
```

I got `ambiguous reference to overloaded definition` compile error on the line `get("test")(t)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete)

Comment: That is not a duplicate of this question, he is already using a Manifest.

Comment: And he does not want to know about how to get around type erasure he wants the to know the  implementation of get function in some other way.

Comment: Your update is really a new question.  I think you should ask it in a new question!

Answer (score 4):

`Manifest` is basically [deprecated](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html). :

> In Scala 2.10, scala.reflect.ClassManifests are deprecated, and it is
>   planned to deprecate scala.reflect.Manifest in favor of TypeTags and
>   ClassTags in an upcoming point release. Thus, it is advisable to
>   migrate any Manifest-based APIs to use Tags.

You should consider using the more modern `ClassTag` or `TypeTag`.  In this case, `ClassTag` works better (since `TypeTags` can't be used in pattern matching):

```
def retrieve(arg: String): List[Parent] = {
    val t = arg match {
      case "Child1" => classTag[Child1]
      case "Child2" => classTag[Child2]
    }

    get(t)
}

def get[T : ClassTag]: List[T] = list collect { 
    case x: T => x 
}
```

You can read more about `ClassTags`, `TypeTags`, and their relationship to `Manifest` in the docs [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).

In case it's not clear, this works because the type constraint on `T` is a *context bound*, meaning the method signature of `get` is equivalent to:

```
def get[T](implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): List[T]
```

So, when we call `get(t)`, we're explicitly specifying the implicit parameter.  Read more about context bounds [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html).

If the context bound or implicit parameter is confusing, you can also achieve your goals by making `get` non-generic:

```
def get(c: ClassTag[_]) = list collect { 
    case x if ClassTag(x.getClass) == c => x 
}
```

This non-generic, non-implicit version might help you resolve your overloading issue.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if the `get` method doesn't have `: Manifest` or `ClassTag` on the `[T]`, is it still possible to do type parameter passing?

Comment: Please see the **UPDATE** section on the question post, I got `ambiguous reference error`.

Comment: @suud I've added an update which allows you to make `get` non-generic.  As for your update, I feel like that's a new question!

Comment: By make it non-generic non-implicit, did you mean unify the overloaded `get` methods into a single `get` method? FYI, in my case I don't have option to change the `get` methods.

Answer (score 3):

Your question boils down to how to retrieve the `Manifest` of a given type. This can be done using the `manifest` method. Then you can explictly pass the manifest, to `get`.

```
class Foo {
  def retrieve(arg: String): List[Parent] = {
    val t = arg match {
      case "Child1" => manifest[Child1]
      case "Child2" => manifest[Child2]
    }

    get(t)
  }

  def get[T <: Parent: Manifest]: List[T] = ...
}
```

As a side note, you should probably use a map to retrieve the manifests (rather than pattern matching) so as to make it more easily editable, or possibly at one point replacing the hard-coded list of types with some init-time computation:

```
object Foo {
  private val manifestByName = Map[String, Manifest[_<:Parent]](
    "Child1" -> manifest[Child1],
    "Child2" -> manifest[Child2]
  )
}
class Foo {
  def retrieve(arg: String): List[Parent] = {
    val t = Foo.manifestByName.getOrElse(arg, sys.error(s"Invalid class name $arg"))
    get(t)
  }

  def get[T <: Parent: Manifest]: List[T] = { println(manifest[T]); Nil }
}
```

Finally, note that `Manifest` is now deprecated, it was superseded with `ClassTag`\ `TypeTag`.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if the `get` method doesn't have `: Manifest` or `ClassTag` on the `[T]`, is it still possible to do type parameter passing?

Comment: Please see the **UPDATE** section on the question post, I got `ambiguous reference error`.