# [Scala]properly reading an object from a file in the presence of type erasure

Tags: scala, dictionary, serialization, deserialization, type-erasure

Let's say I have a map stored on disk and I should like to retrieve it:

```
type myType = Map[something , somethingElse]

...

try{
    val bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path)
    val is = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
    val m = is.readObject().asInstanceOf[myType]
    Some(m)
}catch{
    case _:FileNotFoundException | _:IOException | _:ClassCastException => None
}
```

So far so good. However, as Maps are generic and due to the ever-annoying type erasure, I doubt I can conveniently rely on the `ClassCastException` to make sure that if I ever change `myType`, outdated maps will be discarded.

The thought has crossed my mind to simply hash `myType` and to retrieve and compare the hash prior to retrieving the map, but that feels more like a workaround than a solution. What would be the proper way to handle this?

Edit:
The maps were stored to disk as follows:

```
var myMap : myType = ...

...

try{
    val b = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val os = new ObjectOutputStream(b)
    os.writeObject(myMap)
    Files.write(path, b.toByteArray)
}catch{
...
}
```

Comment: How did you serialize it to disk?

Comment: Please see edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `Manifest`s?

There is a good topic on here that explores getting around type erasure already: [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete)

Comment: I thought Manifests were deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Serializing any generic type in Java/Scala will suffer from type erasure.

There is a way to go around this using reflection and `ClassTags` (backed up with implicit conventions) but it assumes that the compiler has access to the initial types to be preserved. In the case of de-serializing an object from cold-storage, the compiler has no access to the initial type and it won't be able to help you.

Doing something similar to what you describe might be the way to go.

Comment: Or go with a serialization framework like Avro, Parquet, Protocol Buffers.