# pattern matching with case match in scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a match statement like this:

```
val x = y match {
  case array: Array[Float] => call z
  case array: Array[Double] => call z
  case array: Array[BigDecimal] => call z 
  case array: Array[_] => show error
}
```

How do I simplify this to use only two case statements, since first three case statements do same thing, instead of four.

Comment: `case _: T | _: U =>` is the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get around type erasure on Scala? Or, why can't I get the type parameter of my collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete)

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure does not really gives you opportunity to understand how array was typed. What you should do instead is to extract head ( first element) of array and check it's type. For example following code works for me:

```
  List(1,2,3) match {
    case (a:Int) :: tail => println("yep")
  }
```

Comment: Actually type is not erased for arrays. Java arrays, which is the underlying implementation, keep their types. You can see that scalac gives no warnings on the example pattern matching.

Comment: I do not see warning in the case of `List` either `val z = List() match { case x: List[Int] => "println" }`

Comment: That's probably because List() is a list of Nothing and will happily match anything. Try 'List(0.0) match { case x: List[Int] => "println" }' instead' and see how return the same value even though this is a list of double.

Comment: Per my understanding matching happened for `Lists` because of type erasure. but we can not do the same of `Array`. Compiler says types are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

This work, although not very nice:

```
def x(y: Array[_]) = y match {
  case a if a.isInstanceOf[Array[Double]] || 
            a.isInstanceOf[Array[Float]] || 
            a.isInstanceOf[Array[BigDecimal]] => "call z"
  case _ => "show error"
}
```

Would have thought that pattern matching with "|" as below would do the trick. However, this gives *pattern type is incompatible with expected type* on *Array[Float]* and *Array[BigDecimal]*. It might be that matching of generic on this single case where it could work has not been given so much attention:

```
def x(y: Array[_ <: Any]) = y match {
  case a @ (_:Array[Double] | _:Array[Float] | _:Array[BigDecimal]) => "call z"
  case a: Array[_] => "show error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it helps a bit:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

object Tester {
 def test[T: TypeTag](y: Array[T]) = y match {
   case c: Array[_] if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[AnyVal] => "hi"
   case c: Array[_] => "oh"
 }
}

scala> Tester.test(Array(1,2,3))
res0: String = hi

scala> Tester.test(Array(1.0,2.0,3.0))
res1: String = hi

scala> Tester.test(Array("a", "b", "c"))
res2: String = oh
```

Comment: I don't tested it with alternative match patterns, but I think it is possible to write something like: "case c: Array[_] if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Double] || if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Integer]".

Comment: typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[AnyVal] matches with all of scala.Double, scala.Float, scala.Long, scala.Int, scala.Char, scala.Short, and scala.Byte, scala.Unit and scala.Boolean

Comment: @HüseyinZengin yes, and this is the reason I wrote my comment above

Comment: This is only useful if you know the type of the array statically, for the compiler to insert the `TypeTag`. If you just have `c: Array[_]`, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the class of array elements as follows (it will be `null` for non-array types): `c.getClass.getComponentType`. So you can write:

```
if (Set(classOf[Float], classOf[Double], classOf[BigDecimal]).contains(c.getClass.getComponentType)) {
  // call z
} else {
  // show error
}
```

Not particularly Scala'ish, though; I think @thoredge's answer is the best for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check whether the Array is empty first and then if not, just pattern match on Array.head...something like:

```
def x(y: Array[_]) = {
    y.isEmpty match {
      case true => "error"
      case false => y.head match {
         case a:Double | a:BigInt => do whatever
         case _ => "error"  
      }
    }
}
```