# How to declare a function to call cogroup

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to declare a function to get the `cogroup` of two `RDD`. Actually it's a `interSectionByKey`. The code below can't be compiled:

```
def getRetain[K, V](activeUserRdd : RDD[(K, V)], newUserRdd : RDD[(K, V)]): RDD[(K, V)] ={
    activeUserRdd.cogroup(newUserRdd).flatMapValues{
      x => Option((if (!x._1.isEmpty && !x._2.isEmpty) x._2.head else  null).asInstanceOf[V])
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
value cogroup is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)]
```

I think `(K, V)` miss matched the real `[(K, V)]` declared in `cogroup`, but which is the right way to declare in my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `ClassTag`'s to your input types to ensure that erased types `K` and `V` will be accessible at runtime. This is due to [type erasure in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete).

```
scala> import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

scala> def getRetain[K : ClassTag, V : ClassTag](activeUserRdd : RDD[(K, V)], newUserRdd : RDD[(K, V)]): RDD[(K, V)] ={
 |       activeUserRdd.cogroup(newUserRdd).flatMapValues{
 |         x => Option((if (!x._1.isEmpty && !x._2.isEmpty) x._2.head else  null).asInstanceOf[V])
 |       }
 |     }
 getRetain: [K, V](activeUserRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)], newUserRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)]
```

Comment: i don't have this package scala.reflect.TypeTag, do you know some other solutions just use the original scala. I think it can help me a lot to understand scala.
And the error was throwed while compiling. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the import. Please try again.