# Get type of primitive field from an object using Scala reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

So I am attempting to grab the types of each field in a Scala object class:

```
package myapp.model

object MyObject {
  val theInt: Option[Int]
}
```

Using the ReflectionHelper so graciously provided by Brian in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011958/how-to-obtain-generic-type-at-runtime-in-scala/37015558#37015558). I use `getFieldType` but it returns `Option[Object]` instead of what it is, which is `Option[Int]`. The example code in that answer works for a case class, for example:

```
package myapp.model

case class Person(
 name: String,
 age: Option[Int]
)

scala> ReflectionHelper.getFieldType("myapp.model.Person", "age")  // int
res12: Option[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = Some(Option[Int])
```

However, if I run `getFieldType` on a Scala object field, we get this:

```
scala> ReflectionHelper.getFieldType("myapp.model.MyObject$", "theInt")
res10: Option[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = Some(Option[Object])
```

What is different about Scala objects that causes this behavior and how can I get `getFieldType` to return `Option[Int]` instead of `Option[Object]` like it does for the case class?

Here is the ReflectionHelper from the other question for convenience:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => u }
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object ReflectionHelper {

  val classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader

  val mirror = u.runtimeMirror(classLoader)

  def getFieldType(className: String, fieldName: String): Option[Type] = {

    val classSymbol = mirror.staticClass(className)

    for {
      fieldSymbol <- classSymbol.selfType.members.collectFirst({
        case s: Symbol if s.isPublic && s.name.decodedName.toString() == fieldName => s
      })
    } yield {

      fieldSymbol.info.resultType
    }
  }

  def maybeUnwrapFieldType[A](fieldType: Type)(implicit tag: TypeTag[A]): Option[Type] = {
    if (fieldType.typeConstructor == tag.tpe.typeConstructor) {
      fieldType.typeArgs.headOption
    } else {
      Option(fieldType)
    }
  }

  def getFieldClass(className: String, fieldName: String): java.lang.Class[_] = {

    // case normal field return its class
    // case Option field return generic type of Option

    val result = for {
      fieldType <- getFieldType(className, fieldName)
      unwrappedFieldType <- maybeUnwrapFieldType[Option[_]](fieldType)
    } yield {
      mirror.runtimeClass(unwrappedFieldType)
    }

    // Consider changing return type to: Option[Class[_]]
    result.getOrElse(null)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime

val runtimeMirror = runtime.currentMirror

runtimeMirror.staticClass("myapp.model.Person").typeSignature
  .member(TermName("age")).typeSignature // => Option[Int]

runtimeMirror.staticModule("myapp.model.MyObject").typeSignature
  .member(TermName("theInt")).typeSignature // => Option[Int]
```