# Is there a better way to test the generic type (without type arguments) in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, scala-reflect

Given I'm using reflection to go through a list of members (giving me `runtime.universe.Symbol`), how can I check the generic type without the type arguments? In other words, how do I find the members which are `List[]` generic type, regardless of what the type argument is?

Currently I'm using this approach which does work, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

// ...

val listTypeConstructor = typeOf[List[_]].typeConstructor
val myListMembers = currentMirror.reflect(MyObject)
  .symbol
  .asClass
  .typeSignature
  .members
  .filter(member => member.typeSignature.resultType.typeConstructor == listTypeConstructor)
```

This results in a list of `runtime.universe.Symbol` of all the `List[]` members, including any `List[String]`, `List[Int]`, etc. as expected.

The usage of `typeOf[List[_]].typeConstructor` seems a bit messy to me though. Is this the best way to do this kind of filtering?

Comment: What you are looking for actually is not List[_] (as you already know), and the thing is, the generic type itself does not have a constructor, like List itself. so getting the constructor and filtering that in the last step won't work. also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37011958/how-to-obtain-generic-type-at-runtime-in-scala might help

Comment: Why do you consider using `typeOf[List[_]].typeConstructor` messy? `typeOf[List[_]]` is `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Type` of the existential type `List[_]` while `typeOf[List[_]].typeConstructor` is `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Type` of the type constructor `List`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin that's a good point. My feelings derive from the fact that I'm passing `_` to `List[]`, and I haven't looked into `TypeTag`s yet but I think that may address my "messy" complaint. But the more I look at it the more it makes sense. Would you say my code above is indeed the best way to do this filtering then?

Comment: @Daniel Using `typeOf[TC[_]].typeConstructor` seems pretty standard https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/annotation.scala#L286-L288 https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala#L260-L270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. The way I have it in the example above is the standard way.