# Type Erasure in Scala

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I'm rather confused about what's happening here:

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

object Main extends App {
  sealed trait Node

  sealed trait Group

  case class Sheet(
    val splat: String,
    val charname: String, 
    val children: ListMap[String, Node],
    val params0: ListMap[String, Param], //params0 to separate sheet-general parameters

    val note: Option[Note]
    ) extends Node with Group

  case class Attributes(val name: String) extends Node with Group

  case class Param(val name: String, val value: String) extends Node
  case class Note(val note: String) extends Node
```

I've got three versions of a replace function - the last one is the one I'm actually trying to write, the others are just debugging.

```
  class SheetUpdater(s: Sheet) {    
    def replace1[T <: Group](g: T): Unit = {
      s.children.head match {
        case (_, _:Sheet) =>
        case (_, _:Attributes) =>
      }
    }
  }
```

This version throws no warnings, so apparently I have access to the type of `s.children` at runtime.

```
  class SheetUpdater(s: Sheet) {
    def replace2[T <: Group](g: T): Unit = {
      g match {
        case _:Sheet =>
        case _:Attributes =>
      }
    }
  }
```

Neither does this version, so apparently the details of `g`'s type are *also* available at runtime...

```
  class SheetUpdater(s: Sheet) {
    def replace3[T <: Group](g: T): Unit = {
      s.children.head match {
        case (_, _:T) => //!
        case (_, _:Attributes) =>
      }
    }
  }
```

... but even so, this ends up throwing me the dreaded `Abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure` warning. What's going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Scala, generics are erased at runtime, which means that the runtime type of `List[Int]` and `List[Boolean]` is actually the same. This is because the JVM as a whole erases generic types. All this is due because the JVM wanted to remain backwards compatible way back when generics were first introduced...

There is a way around this in Scala using a `ClassTag`, which is an implicit parameter that then can be threaded around with whatever generic you are using.

You can think of `: ClassTag` as passing the type of the generic as an argument. (It is syntactic sugar for passing an implicit parameter of type `ClassTag[T]`.)

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class SheetUpdater(s: Sheet) {
  def replace3[T <: Group : ClassTag](g: T): Unit = {
    s.children.head match {
      case (_, _:T) => //!
      case (_, _:Attributes) =>
    }
  }
}
```

[Newer answers of this question have more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete?rq=1)

Comment: I suppose my question then is "where's my generic"? It's not like I'm matching against `List[T]` or something similar, so...

Comment: @linkhyrule5 the generic is `s.children: ListMap[String, Node] `.

Comment: Sure, but I decomposed that - I'm matching against the children, which should still be well typed.

Comment: Turned out to be the Tuple.