# Scala method type parameterization

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to get a better handle on understanding methods parameterized by types and have this piece of code -

```
 def inferType[T, U](x: T, y: U): Unit = y match {
    case _: T => println("T")
    case _    => println("Not T")
  }
 inferType("0", 11) // call 1
 inferType(0, 11)   // call 2
```

I would have expected call 1 to have printed "Not T" and call 2 to have printed "T". However, its printing "T" in both cases. Obviously I am missing something here. Can someone help me with why pattern matching is not matching the generic type T here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570948/type-erasure-in-scala

Comment: https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html

Answer (score 2):

The JVM is performing type-erasure, so at runtime all generic types are actually `Object`, and your match is checking whether `y` is of type `T = Object`, which it is.

You can get around this [using `TypeTag`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232195/2174693), but this is an anti-pattern in most cases.