# How to use scala to test variable of Type Map?

Tags: scala

The following code has the warning

`value.isInstanceOf[Map[Any,Any]]`

```
non-variable type argument Any in type Map[Any,Any] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

How to eliminate the warning while still able to check data of the Type Map[Any,Any]?

Thx :）

Comment: `Any` is symptom the type safety is not ok there

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
value.isInstanceOf[Map[_, _]]
```

Additional approaches are described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete).