# How to tell Param[Any] from Param[Array[Any] in runtime in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I'm writing a piece of Scala code that would construct a Spark-ML pipeline from config file for me. I want to be able to instantiate objects that extend *Params* class (i.e. *PipelineStage*) and a *Pipeline* itself.

```
pipeline {
    class = "org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline"
    stages = ["pca", "vectorAssembler"]
    vectorAssembler {
        class = "org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler"
        inputCols = ["pcacol","col1","col2","col3"]
        outputCol = "features"
    }
    pca {
    ....
    }
}
```

At the moment I instantiate the class and set parameters by calling *Params#set* method.
I want the parser to be as general as possible and I want to be able to set parameters of any type, including privitives, arrays of primitives and arrays of objects (e.g. *Pipeline#stages*).
The problem is I can't tell distinguish type parameters of the setter. I look at the type of required parameter and cast config's value to this type.

```
 param match {
      case p: DoubleArrayParam =>
        ...
      case p: IntArrayParam =>
        ...
      case p: StringArrayParam =>
        ...
      case p: Param[Array[Params]] =>
        ...
      case p =>
        ...
```

In runtime *Param[String]*, *Param[Array[String]]* and *Param[Array[Params]]* are the same. For string arrays and arrays of primitives there are separate classes, *DoubleArrayParam*, *IntArrayParam*, *StringArrayParam*, but I can't find a way to tell array of *Params* from simple *String*, as Param[Any] matches penultimate case in the code above.

The only solution I came to is to parse *Pipeline* config separately, but that means I might come to other specific cases in future.

Comment: I hope that you can find some useful information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete

Comment: @HosamAly thanks for the link, I learned a lot from it.
Unfortunately it didn't help much in this case as I found my *Param[_]* objects to be type-erased already.
As a result I had to use reflection to extract types from corresponding fields