# scala syntax explanation involving higher order functions, type parameter and return type

Tags: scala, types, syntax, parameters, explain

I am having problems understanding the Scala syntax, please advice. I have two snippets of code.

```
abstract class Try[T] {

  def flatMap[U](f: T => Try[U]): Try[U] = this match {
    case Success(x) => try f(x) catch { case NonFatal(ex) => Failure(ex) }
    case fail: Failure => fail
  }
}
```

My understanding:

- flatMap received as parameter a function f. In turn this function f 
  receives type parameter T and returns Try of type parameter U.
- flatMap ultimately return Try of type parameter U.

Q1 - Is my understanding correct?

Q2 - what is the relation between the return type from f (namely Try[U]) and the return type of flat map Try[U]? Does it have to be the same?

> def flatMap[U](f: T => **Try[U]**): **Try[U]**

Or can I somehow have something like

> def flatMap[U](f: T => **Option[U]**): **Try[U]**

In the last snippet of code, I guess that, after I use the function f inside my flatMap, I would need to make the connection between the output of f (namely Option[U]) and the final output demanded by flatMap (I mean Try[U])

> EDIT

This code is taken from a scala course. here is the full code (some people asked about it). I just want to understand the syntax.

```
abstract class Try[T] {

def flatMap[U](f: T => Try[U]): Try[U] = this match {
    case Success(x) => try f(x) catch { case NonFatal(ex) => Failure(ex) }
    case fail: Failure => fail
}

def map[U](f: T => U): Try[U] = this match {
    case Success(x) => Try(f(x))
    case fail: Failure => fail
}
}
```

Comment: ok. do you prefer me to fragment the question?

Comment: Is this your own implementation of `Try` or have you seen it somewhere else? This is not how `Try` is implemented in `2.12.4`

Comment: added full code in the question

Answer (score 0):

**Q1** Largely correct, but just to clarify, all of this happens at compile time - T is not known at runtime (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094173/5986907))

**Q2** Of course you can create a method with signature

```
...[U](f: T => Option[U]): Try[U]
```

and you're free to call that method flatMap, but it won't be a standard flatMap:

```
trait T[A] {
  flatMap[B](f: A => T[B]): T[B]
}
```

There are mathematical reasons for the form of flatMap (which also have implications in Scala's implementation of for expressions). To avoid confusion ...

Rather than altering flatMap's signature, wrap your `T => Option[U]` with an `Option[U] => Try[U]` to create a `T => Try[U]` *before* passing it to flatMap.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1 - Is my understanding correct?

It's hard to comment based on your sample code which has method implementation in an abstract class while no concrete classes are defined.  Lets consider the following toy version of `Try` extracted from the [Scala API](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.6/src/library/scala/util/Try.scala) with the `flatMap` implementation in its concrete classes:

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal 

sealed abstract class MyTry[+T] {
  def flatMap[U](f: T => MyTry[U]): MyTry[U]
}

object MyTry {
  def apply[T](r: => T): MyTry[T] =
    try MySuccess(r) catch { case NonFatal(e) => MyFailure(e) }
}

final case class MyFailure[+T](exception: Throwable) extends MyTry[T] {
  override def flatMap[U](f: T => MyTry[U]): MyTry[U] =
    this.asInstanceOf[MyTry[U]]
}

final case class MySuccess[+T](value: T) extends MyTry[T] {
  override def flatMap[U](f: T => MyTry[U]): MyTry[U] =
    try f(value) catch { case NonFatal(e) => MyFailure(e) }
}
```

Testing it out with the following function `f: T => MyTry[U]` where `T` = String and `U` = Int, I hope it helps answer your question:

```
val f: String => MyTry[Int] = s => s match {
  case "bad" => MyFailure(new Exception("oops"))
  case s => MySuccess(s.length)
}

MyTry("abcde").flatMap(f)
// res1: MyTry[Int] = MySuccess(5)

MyTry("bad").flatMap(f)
// res2: MyTry[Int] = MyFailure(java.lang.Exception: oops)
```

> Q2 - what is the relation between the return type from f (namely Try[U])
>   and the return type of flat map Try[U]? Does it have to be the same?

In Scala, `flatMap` is a common method defined in many of Scala containers/collections such as `Option[T]`, `List[T]`, `Try[T]`, `Future[T]`, with a standard signature:

```
class Container[T] {
  def flatMap[U](f: T => Container[U]): Container[U]
}
```

If you want to have a special map that takes a `T => Container1[U]` function and returns a `Container2[U]`, it'd probably best not to name it `flatMap`.