# Is there workaround against type erasure?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-parameter

I would like to pattern-match against a generic parameter. I wrote the following example:

```
new Cls().processA("")   //prints B: C

sealed trait Tr[A, B <: A, C <: A]{
  def getA(str: String): A

  final def processA(str: String): Unit = getA(str) match {
    case b: B => println(s"B: " + b)
    case c: C => println(s"C: " + c)
  }
}

sealed trait A
final case class B() extends A
final case class C() extends A

final class Cls extends Tr[A, B, C] {
  override def getA(str: String): A = C()
}
```

I understand that `B` and `C` parameters are erasured to their lower bound `A`. Maybe there is some workaround to pattern-match against type parameters?

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094173/5986907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case yes, there is: add `import scala.reflect.ClassTag` and change the definition of `Tr` to

```
sealed abstract class Tr[A, B <: A : ClassTag, C <: A : ClassTag]
```

Note that this *won't* affect `is/asInstanceOf`.

Comment: Does it introduce some runtime cost?

Comment: Yes, but it should be pretty small (of course, saying that isn't a substitute for checking performance in your case).

Comment: Agree. From the quick glance at bytecode generated with `ClassTag`s added it uses `ClassTag:unapply` returning option. So the cost is similar to an `instance of` which is pretty small.

Comment: I have one more clarification. You said that it would not affect `isInstanceOf`, but we can use `implicitly[ClassTag[B]]` to perform the instance checking, can't we?

Comment: Yes, we can. Or matching: `x match { case _: B => true; case _ => false }`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ClassTag` so that it will be possible to check this on runtime.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

sealed abstract class Tr[A, B <: A : ClassTag, C <: A : ClassTag]{
  def getA(str: String): A

  final def processA(str: String): Unit = getA(str) match {
    case b: B => println(s"B: " + b)
    case c: C => println(s"C: " + c)
  }
}
```

For this to work you need to replace trait with abstract class because traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds.