# How to receive Generic Event in Actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I tried to write a generic Actor and it can receive generic event

```
case class CreateEvent[T](t: T)

trait MyBaseActor[Type] extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case CreateEvent(t: Type) => ....
    }
}
```

Then, I create an real actor

```
case class HasName(name: String)

class MyActor extends MyBaseActor[HasName]
```

And I expect `MyActor` can handle message `Create(HasName("hello")` as well. But when I compile code, I got this warning:

```
abstract type pattern Type is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

And my actor can't receive `CreateEvent` also. Maybe I don't understand enough about Generic in scala, please help me explain why it not work and how can I fix it

Comment: try this T<:Type in your CreateEvent class

Comment: Type here is just Generic type, I don't have any trait or class for it

Comment: create type name Type and use it like this or you can create empty trait or case object.

Comment: In your case I´d suggest taking a look to Akka Typed: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/typed/index.html

Comment: I suggest you read about type erasure in Scala, you may find some solutions for your case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because of type erasure. In runtime, any instance of `CreateEvent` has type `CreateEvent[Object]` so you can't match its generic type.

To work around it you can use `ClassTag`:

```
trait MyBaseActor[Type] extends Actor {
  val classTag: ClassTag[Type]

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CreateEvent(t) if classTag.runtimeClass.isInstance(t) =>
      val typedT: Type = t.asInstanceOf[Type]
      ....
  }
}
class MyActor() extends MyBaseActor[HasName] {
  override final val classTag: ClassTag[HasName] = implicitly[ClassTag[HasName]]
}
```