# Pattern matching on a list of generics

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

I have a class which contains a sequence of a generic type like:

```
sealed trait Interface {}

case class Imp1() extends Interface {}
case class Imp2() extends Interface {}

case class Wrapper[+I <: Interface](interface: I) {}

case class WrapperList(list: Seq[Wrapper[Interface]]) {
    ...
}
```

In the `WrapperList` I want to be able to iterate through the Sequence of wrappers and pattern match on each ones type, eg.

```
def getImp1s(remaining: Seq[Wrapper[Interface]] = list): Seq[Wrapper[Imp1]] = {
  if (remaining.length == 0) Seq()
  else remaining.head match {
    case wrapper: Wrapper[Imp1] => get(remaining.tail) :+ wrapper
    case _                      => get(remaining.tail)
  }
}
```

As you can probably guess I'm running into

```
non-variable type argument Playground.Imp1 in type pattern Playground.Wrapper[Playground.Imp1] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

To overcome this I was under the impression I could use `TypeTags` or `ClassTags` to preserve the type, something like:

```
case class Wrapper[+I <: Interface](interface: I)(implicit tag: TypeTag[I]) {}
```

However this doesn't seem to work, I still get the same warning. Could someone explain how I can match using the TypeTag? I'd rather avoid creating concrete versions of my generic class which extend a generic abstract class, but do understand that this is maybe the easiest solution.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21640639/9128490) should help

Comment: Due type erasure this kind of designs will be painful to work with. Maybe, it would be better if you can explain what are your constraints and what do you need to do?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, I was kind of hopping that TypeTags would be a magic bullet that would just allow me to match on generics like they were concrete with no extra effort. I'm just learning Scala and was trying to do something in a weird way to help me understand how things work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import shapeless.TypeCase

val `Wrapper[Imp1]` = TypeCase[Wrapper[Imp1]]

def getImp1s(remaining: Seq[Wrapper[Interface]]): Seq[Wrapper[Imp1]] = {
  if (remaining.isEmpty) Seq()
  else remaining.head match {
    case `Wrapper[Imp1]`(wrapper) => getImp1s(remaining.tail) :+ wrapper
    case _                        => getImp1s(remaining.tail)
  }
}

getImp1s(Seq(Wrapper(Imp1()), Wrapper(Imp2()), Wrapper(new Interface {}))) 
// List(Wrapper(Imp1()))
getImp1s(Seq(Wrapper(Imp2()), Wrapper(Imp1()), Wrapper(new Interface {}))) 
// List(Wrapper(Imp1()))
```

The same can be achieved without Shapeless with custom extractor

```
object `Wrapper[Imp1]` {
  def unapply(arg: Any): Option[Wrapper[Imp1]] = arg match {
    case Wrapper(Imp1()) => Some(Wrapper(Imp1()))
    case _               => None
  }
}
```

or directly

```
def getImp1s(remaining: Seq[Wrapper[Interface]]): Seq[Wrapper[Imp1]] = {
  if (remaining.isEmpty) Seq()
  else remaining.head match {
    case Wrapper(Imp1()) => getImp1s(remaining.tail) :+ Wrapper(Imp1())
    case _               => getImp1s(remaining.tail)
  }
}
```

or

```
def getImp1s(remaining: Seq[Wrapper[Interface]]): Seq[Wrapper[Imp1]] = {
  if (remaining.isEmpty) Seq()
  else remaining.head match {
    case Wrapper(_: Imp1) => getImp1s(remaining.tail) :+ Wrapper(Imp1())
    case _                => getImp1s(remaining.tail)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the really comprehensive response it has cleared up how type tags work really well :)