# How to pattern match on generic type in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

Let's suppose we have a generic class `Container`:

```
case class Container[+A](value: A)
```

We then want to pattern match a `Container` with a `Double` and a `Container` of `Any`:

```
val double = Container(3.3)  
var container: Container[Any] = double
```

To do this, we would normally write:

```
container match {  
  case c: Container[String] => println(c.value.toUpperCase)
  case c: Container[Double] => println(math.sqrt(c.value))  
  case _ => println("_")  
}
```

However, the compiler gives two warnings, one for each of the first two cases. For example, the first warning says: "non-variable type argument String in type pattern Container[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure". Because of the erasure, it is impossible during runtime to distinguish between different kinds of containers and the first catch will be matched. As a consequence, container of type `Container[Double]` will be matched by the first case, which catches `Container[String]` objects, so `toUpperCase` method will be called on a `Double` and a `java.lang.ClassCastException` will be thrown.

How to match a `Container` parametrized by a particular type?

Comment: I've added an answer to the same question over there: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181533/can-we-elegantly-match-an-erased-type-in-scala/35181934#35181934)

Answer (score 33):

Maybe this will help

```
 def matchContainer[A: Manifest](c: Container[A]) = c match {
      case c: Container[String] if manifest <:< manifest[String] => println(c.value.toUpperCase)
      case c: Container[Double] if manifest <:< manifest[Double] => println(math.sqrt(c.value))
      case c: Container[_] => println("other")
    }
```

**Edit:**

As  Impredicative pointed out, Manifest is deprecated. Instead you could do the following:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
def matchContainer[A: TypeTag](c: Container[A]) = c match {
      case c: Container[String] if typeOf[A] <:< typeOf[String] => println("string: " + c.value.toUpperCase)
      case c: Container[Double] if typeOf[A] <:< typeOf[Double] => println("double" + math.sqrt(c.value))
      case c: Container[_] => println("other")
    }
```

Comment: Worth noting that `Manifest` is deprecated in favour of `TypeTag` in recent versions of Scala.

Answer (score 32):

In general rarry's answer is correct, for your case however it can be simplified, because your container only contains a single value of a generic type, so you can match on that value's type directly:

```
container match {
  case Container(x: String) => println("string")
  case Container(x: Double) => println("double")
  case _ => println("w00t")
}
```

Answer (score 13):

A possible workaround for this could be to use `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf`.

```
container match {  
  case Container(x) if x.isInstanceOf[String] =>  
    println(x.asInstanceOf[String].toUpperCase)  
  case Container(x) if x.isInstanceOf[Double] =>  
    println(math.sqrt(x.asInstanceOf[Double]))  
  case _ => println("_")  
}
```

This works, but it doesn't look elegant at all. Professor Martin Odersky, the creator of Scala, says that `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf` should be avoided.

As Rob Norris pointed me out, on the forum of the course "*Functional programming in Scala*" from Coursera, matching by type is a bad practice: `case foo: Bar => ...`. Scala encourages to take advantage of static typing and avoid checking type during runtime. This is consistent with the philosophy of Haskell/ML world. Instead of matching *types*, `case` clauses should match *constructors*.

To solve the `Container` matching problem, a special container for each type can be defined:

```
class Container[+A](val value: A)

case class StringContainer(override val value: String)
  extends Container(value)

case class DoubleContainer(override val value: Double)
  extends Container(value)
```

And now *constructors* will be matched, not *types*:

```
container match {
  case StringContainer(x) => println(x.toUpperCase)
  case DoubleContainer(x) => println(math.sqrt(x))
  case _ => println("_")
}
```

Apparently, we could be defined `unapply` methods in two objects, `StringContainer` and `DoubleContainer` and use the same match as above, instead of extending the `Container` class:

```
case class Container[+A](val value: A)

object StringContainer {
  def unapply(c: Container[String]): Option[String] = Some(c.value)
}


object DoubleContainer {
  def unapply(c: Container[Double]): Option[Double] = Some(c.value)
}
```

But this does not work, again, because of JVM type erasure.

A reference to Rob Norris post, which lead me to this answer can be found here: https://class.coursera.org/progfun-002/forum/thread?thread_id=842#post-3567 . Unfortunately, you can't access it unless you are enrolled in the Coursera course.

Answer (score 5):

Note: you also have an alternative with [Miles Sabin](https://github.com/milessabin)'s [Shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) ([already mentioned by Miles in 2012 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8821911/6309)).

You can see an example in "[Ways to pattern match generic types in Scala](https://gist.github.com/jkpl/5279ee05cca8cc1ec452fc26ace5b68b)" from [Jaakko Pallari](https://twitter.com/lepovirta)

> **`Typeable` is a type class that provides the ability to cast values from `Any` type to a specific type**.
>   The result of the casting operation is an `Option` where the `Some` value will contain the successfully casted value, and the `None` value represents a cast failure.
>
> `TypeCase` bridges `Typeable` and pattern matching. It's essentially an extractor for `Typeable` instances

```
import shapeless._

def extractCollection[T: Typeable](a: Any): Option[Iterable[T]] = {
  val list = TypeCase[List[T]]
  val set  = TypeCase[Set[T]]
  a match {
    case list(l) => Some(l)
    case set(s)  => Some(s)
    case _       => None
  }
}

val l1: Any = List(1, 2, 3)
val l2: Any = List[Int]()
val s:  Any = Set(1, 2, 3)

extractCollection[Int](l1)    // Some(List(1, 2, 3))
extractCollection[Int](s)     // Some(Set(1, 2, 3))
extractCollection[String](l1) // None
extractCollection[String](s)  // None
extractCollection[String](l2) // Some(List()) // Shouldn't this be None? We'll get back to this.
```

> While `Typeable` may look like it has what it takes to solve type erasure, it's still subject to the same behaviour as any other runtime code.
>   This can be seen in the last lines of the previous code examples where empty lists were recognized as string lists even when they were specified to be integer lists. This is because `Typeable` casts are based on the values of the list. If the list is empty, then naturally that is a valid string list and a valid integer list (or any other list for that matter)

Comment: The linked article really gives an excellent treatment of this topic, and also covers the other alternatives (runtime reflection, etc.)