# Compilation error with Ordered in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I'm having some trouble implementing an immutable BST in Scala. The problem seems to be that by some reason although I've defined `K` to be as `Ordered[K]` (2nd line), it actually is being considered by the Scala compiler to be an `Any`. Why?

```
abstract class BST
sealed case class Node[K <: Ordered[K], V](key : K, value : V, left : BST, right : BST) extends BST
sealed case class Empty() extends BST

object BST {
  def empty = Empty()

  def add[K <: Ordered[K], V](key : K, value : V, tree : BST) : BST = tree match {
    case Empty() => new Node(key, value, Empty(), Empty())
    case Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, left, right) =>
      if (key < nodeKey) new Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, add(key, value, left), right)
      else if (key > nodeKey) new Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, left, add(key, value, right))
      else new Node(key, value, left, right)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, thanks for the help. But I think you all just got things way too complicated. The only problem seemed to be that BST had to also be BST[K, V]:

```
abstract class BST[K <: Ordered[K], V]
sealed case class Node[K <: Ordered[K], V](key : K, value : V, left : BST[K, V], right : BST[K, V]) extends BST[K, V]
sealed case class Empty[K <: Ordered[K], V]() extends BST[K, V]

object BST {
  def empty = Empty()

  def add[K <: Ordered[K], V](key : K, value : V, tree : BST[K, V]) : BST[K, V] = tree match {
    case Empty() => new Node(key, value, Empty(), Empty())
    case Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, left, right) =>
      if (key < nodeKey) new Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, add(key, value, left), right)
      else if (key > nodeKey) new Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, left, add(key, value, right))
      else new Node(key, value, left, right)
  }
}
```

This compiles and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler seems to be confused by you telling it that the generic type `K` is a subtype of `Ordered[K]`. I'm a bit confused by that as well. That's like saying that `A` is a subtype of `List[A]`, and I can't wrap my head around that either. How can a type be a subtype of a list of that type? Recursively defining types may work in some cases, but I don't believe this is one of them.

From the context, I feel like the actual syntax you want is `[K: Ordered]`. This tells the compiler to expect a generic type `K` for which there is an implicit `Ordered[K]` in scope. It is syntactic sugar that changes your `Node` class to look like this:

```
sealed case class Node[K, V](key : K, value : V, left : BST, right : BST)(implicit evidence: Ordered[K]) extends BST
```

Comment: Hm? In Java I would just state that K extends Comparable<K> and there is no confusion to be had.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the type erasure on the JVM - erased to `Any` in Scala. See this answer for example on how to work around this problem: [How to pattern match on generic type in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056645/how-to-pattern-match-on-generic-type-in-scala). Alternatively consider passing an implicit `Ordering` like this:

```
sealed case class Node[K, V](key : K, value : V, left : BST, right : BST,
  implicit cmp: Ordering[K]) extends BST
```

Comment: Implicit parameters need to be in a new parameter list. You need `..., right: BST)(implicit cmp: Ordering[K])`.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this down to a compiling version, it's probably not minimal though and some explicit annotations can probably be removed. If you need more explanation, please leave a comment.

```
abstract class BST[K : Ordering, V]
sealed case class Node[K : Ordering, V](key : K, value : V, left : BST[K, V], right : BST[K,V]) extends BST[K, V]
sealed case class Empty[K : Ordering, V]() extends BST[K, V]

object BST {
  def empty[K : Ordering, V] = Empty[K,V]()

  def add[K : Ordering, V](key : K, value : V, tree : BST[K,V]) : BST[K,V] = tree match {
    case Empty() => new Node(key, value, Empty(), Empty())
    case Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, left, right) =>
      if (implicitly[Ordering[K]].lt(key,  nodeKey)) new Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, add(key, value, left), right)
      else if (implicitly[Ordering[K]].gt(key,nodeKey)) new Node(nodeKey, nodeValue, left, add(key, value, right))
      else new Node(key, value, left, right)
  }
}
```