# odd isInstanceOf behavior in Scala

Tags: scala, scalatest

using the [ScalaTest/FlatSpec](http://scalatest.org) library I am testing the types of returned values from a random number generator using functional state:

```
it should "return (\"{someRandomNumber}\", rng2) on nonNegativeInt.map(_.toString)" in {
    val s = RNG.map(RNG.nonNegativeInt)(_.toString)(rng)
    assert(s.isInstanceOf[(Int, RNG)]) // WRONG but PASS!!
    assert(s._2 !== rng)
}
```

now if you notice the incorrect `isInstanceOf[(Int, RNG)]` you would think that this would produce a fail, however it succeeds.

the following code demonstrates that this passes as long as the tuple has the correct arity:

```
it should "not work" in {
    assert(("123", rng).isInstanceOf[(Int, RNG)]) // PASS
    assert(("123", rng).isInstanceOf[(String, Nothing)]) // PASS
    assert(("123", rng).isInstanceOf[(Exception, Array[_])]) // PASS
}
```

but if the tuple has one type parameter:

```
it should "also not work" in {
    assert(("123").isInstanceOf[Int]) // FAIL
}
```

What is going on here? how should I test the inner parameterized types?

Comment: Type erasure of `Tuple2[A,B]`. Use `TypeTag` for tests.

Answer (score 3):

Don't ever forget that scala is backed by plain old java, inheriting all its nuances. Java performs [runtime type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339708/1349366) for generic classes. So your `(Int, Rng)` in runtime is `Tuple2(Object, Object)`, so is your `s`.

You can find some useful information how to work around that issue in scala [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35181934/1349366).