# How to pattern match with dependent type without using it?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure, path-dependent-type

This is hard to phrase, so please, let me show an example:

```
trait Cache

trait QueryLike {
  type Result
}

trait Query[A] extends QueryLike {
  type Result = A
  def exec: Result
}

trait CachedQuery[A] extends QueryLike {
  type Result = A
  def execWithCache(cache: Cache): Result
}

def exec(query: QueryLike)(implicit cache: Cache): query.Result = query match {
  case q: Query[query.Result] => q.exec
  case cq: CachedQuery[query.Result] => cq.execWithCache(cache)
}
```

This compiles and runs fine as pattern matching is done on different types (`Query`, `CachedQuery`) instead of relying on generics like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056645/how-to-pattern-match-on-generic-type-in-scala).

But I still get compiler warning like :

> Warning:(18, 12) abstract type Result in type pattern A$A4.this.Query[query.Result] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
>     case q: Query[query.Result] => q.exec

Since I don't work on dependent type `query.Result` directly in anyway (like casting it for different operations), it'd be ideal to just erase it completely and do away with the warning. But unfortunately, using wildcard doesn't work for a good reason:

```
...
case q: Query[_] => q.exec // type mismatch
case cq: CachedQuery[_] => cq.execWithCache(cache)
...
```

Is there a better way to do this without generating compiler warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error isn't really specific to path-dependent types. If you tried to match on any `Query[A]` you would get the same error, because the type parameter `A` is erased at runtime. In this case, it's not possible that the type parameter can be anything other than the type you're looking for. Since a `Query[A]` is a `QueryLike { type Result = A}`, it should also be a `Query[query.Result]`, though this is a somewhat unusual way to look at it. You *could* use the `@unchecked` annotation to suppress the warning, if you wish:

```
def exec(query: QueryLike)(implicit cache: Cache): query.Result = query match {
  case q: Query[query.Result @unchecked] => q.exec
  case cq: CachedQuery[query.Result @unchecked] => cq.execWithCache(cache)
}
```

While it's tough to say if this would apply to your actual use-case, you could also restructure your code to avoid matching entirely, and handle it (possibly) more elegantly via polymorphism. Since the last `exec` requires an implicit `Cache` *anyway*, it wouldn't seem to hurt to allow that for each `QueryLike`. Your API can be more uniform this way, and you wouldn't need to figure out which method to call.

```
trait Cache

trait QueryLike {
  type Result
  def exec(implicit cache: Cache): Result
}

trait Query[A] extends QueryLike {
  type Result = A
}

trait CachedQuery[A] extends QueryLike {
  type Result = A
}

def exec(query: QueryLike)(implicit cache: Cache): query.Result = query.exec
```

If `Query[A]` requires an `exec` without a `Cache`, you could also provide an overload with a `DummyImplicit` to allow it to work without one.

```
def exec(implicit d: DummyImplicit): Result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I thought of passing `cache` to all `QueryLike`, I decided not to as it seemed to negate the code clarity and `CachedQuery` is somewhat an exceptional case anyway so it was quite discouraging to do so. My acutal class with `exec` has `cache` object in scope. `@unchecked` annotation seems interesting. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: You might also find another way to resolve the `Cache` for the `CachedQuery` other than the implicit, which would allow you to remove it from the signature and make everything uniform. _How_ is difficult to say, because I don't know the specific use-case. But right now if you have a `query: Query[A]`, and pass it to `exec` (with the match), it still requires the implicit `Cache`, which is the same problem.

Comment: Oh no. What I meant by scope wasn't the implicit. My class looks somewhat like this: `class DB { val cache: Cache = ???; def exec(query: QueryLike) = ??? }`. So the caller of `exec` is completely oblivious to whether the query is executed with cache or not. The code example above wasn't very clear as to that. I added implicit just for the sake of making it compile.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem seems to be very specific to path depended types: the problem is the type of q and cq. q.Result is a incompatible type to query.Result because the Scala type checker does not know, that query and q and qc have to be the same reference.

Thus, Query[query.Result] actually does require a runtime type check. I've noticed this, when I tried to remove the type parameter and just use the inner result. Then the pattern matches do not generate a warning any more but the return type of q.exec won't be compatible with query.Result.

One solution, without using @unchecked or asInstanceOf etc. would be to turn Result into a type parameter of QueryLike. In general, you should not use abstract type members for things that you want to take "out of a context" an pass around freely. So turning a type member into a type parameter somewhere in the inheritance hierarchy is kind of strange.

So this works fine, as the compiler knows, that he does not have to check the type parameter:

```
trait QueryLike[A] {

}

trait Query[A] extends QueryLike[A] {
  def exec: A
}

trait CachedQuery[A] extends QueryLike[A] {
  def execWithCache(cache: Cache): A
}

def exec[A](query: QueryLike[A])(implicit cache: Cache): A = query match {
  case q: Query[A] => q.exec
  case cq: CachedQuery[A] => cq.execWithCache(cache)
}
```

Another approach would be to add the method to a common base trait of CachedQuery and Query.

```
trait QueryLike {
  type Result
}

trait Query[A] extends QueryLike with ExecWithCache {
  type Result = A
  def exec: Result
  override def execWithCache(implicit cache: Cache) = exec
}

trait CachedQuery[A] extends QueryLike with ExecWithCache {
  type Result = A
  def exec(cache: Cache): Result
  override def execWithCache(implicit cache: Cache) = exec(cache)
}

trait ExecWithCache extends QueryLike {
  def execWithCache(implicit cache: Cache): Result
}
```

To change this, Scala would probably have to be able to determine when two stable accessors are identical.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate on switching to type parameter in place of abstract type? As far as I can tell, it still requires a type parameter on `Query` and `CachedQuery` like: `def exec[A](query: QueryLike[A]): A = q match { case q: Query[A] => ???; case cq: CachedQuery[A] = ??? }`.

Comment: I've included the code in my answer. This is more or less the standard way to do this, I assumed you had some reason for not doing it that way.