# Scala case pattern match error in case of Option[String]

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a function with the variable number of arguments

```
def foo(args: String*)
```

What this function does is, it eliminates the empty strings and separate rest of the strings with a comma (`,`).

```
def foo(args: String*) = {
  args.flatMap {
    case str if str.isEmpty => None
    case str => Some(str)
  }.mkString(", ")
}
```

When I extended this function to support `Option[String]` arguments

```
def foo(args: Any*) = {
  args.flatMap {
    case str: String if str.isEmpty => None
    case str: Option[String] if str.getOrElse("").isEmpty => None
    case str => Some(str)
  }.mkString(", ")
}
```

I got a warning saying

> warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern
>   Option[String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

And when I pass arguments

```
foo("", "Hello", Some(""), Some("what"))
```

I got error

> scala.MatchError: Some(what) (of class scala.Some)   at
>   $anonfun$makeAddress$1.apply(:12)   at
>   $anonfun$makeAddress$1.apply(:12)

How should I create such function supporting `Option[String]` as well?

Comment: I got one possible solution https://gist.github.com/fahadsiddiqui/b530a093a643f489a9a661606d479f30, but please let me know if there is an optimal solution.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056645/how-to-pattern-match-on-generic-type-in-scala

Comment: Using `Any` is a strong code smell - it's the top of the [Type Hierarchy](docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified…). As a result, the compiler can't help you out, i.e. prevent run-time errors, since the type isn't useful given its broadness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use collect and avoid Option altogether:

```
def foo(args: String*): String = {
  args.collect{case s if ! s.isEmpty => s}.mkString(",")
}
```

collect is the equivalent of filter combined with map.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your solution

```
def foo(args: Any*) = {
  args.flatMap {
    case str: String if !str.isEmpty => Option(str)
    case Some(str:String) if !str.isEmpty  => Option(str)
    case _ => None
  }.mkString(", ")
}
```

Comment: In addtion, in your code, there is a bug if you use below

println(foo("", "Hello", Some(null), Some("what")))

Comment: shouldn't it be Some(str) instead of Option(str)?

Comment: no , Some(str) is mostly used for pattern match. The issue is Some(null) != None  and Option(null) == None . You can have try in scala REPL.