# Scala match on generic type

Tags: scala, generics, types, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I am trying to do a match on a value based on its type, and there is a case where the expected type is a generic, like below:

```scala
def foo(bar: Matchable) = bar match
    case (bar: Vector[String]) => println(bar.mkString(","))
```

However, I get the following warning at runtime:

> the type test for Vector[String] cannot be checked at runtime

Why cannot it be checked and how could I overcome this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056645/how-to-pattern-match-on-generic-type-in-scala

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete

Comment: I would recommend taking a couple of steps back and reconsider the design that lead to runtime type checking.

Comment: I have to manipulate entries like `[1,[2,[3,[4,[5,6,7]]]],8,9]` so it's not easy (it's for Advent of Code day 13 FYI)

Comment: `sealed trait ListOrValue[A]; case class ListCase[A](list: List[ListOrValue[A]]) extends ListOrValue[A]; case class ValueCase[A](value: A) extends ListOrValue[A]` - a discriminating union which allows recursion would let you preserve type safety. Something which "`Vector[Any]` where `Any` should actually be `Vector[Any]` or `String`" wouldn't allow. There would be also some other options esp in Scala 3 (e.g. sum types + `TypeTest`), but I wouldn't recommend them for an entry level. `sealed`/`enum` would be easier to understand.