# scala accessing a list object inside another list

Tags: scala, collections

I am trying to access a list object inside of another list with a specific type

```
val x = List ("item1" , "item2" , List ("a","b","c"))
val list_from_x :List [String]= x(2) // producing error
```

I need my `list_from_x` of type to be of `List [String]`
any idea how to I do such conversion ?

Comment: Or using a shapeless `HList`

Comment: @theone what do u mean?

Comment: I was replying to a comment that seems to have been deleted. Anyway, I've posted an answer detailing `HList` some more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `x` is of type `List[Object]`**, because you've used two different (otherwise unrelated) classes as elements of that list.
You'll be unable to access elements other than of type `Any` without a type cast:

```
val listFromX = x(2).asInstanceOf[List[String]]
```

This is not type-safe, so you'll want to check element types (`x(2).isInstanceOf[List[_]]`) or pattern matching.

---

** Use the REPL to verify this; though `val x: List[Any] = List ("item1" , "item2" , List ("a,b,c"))` works

Comment: Pattern matching is a safer but more verbose way to do this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171489/explicit-type-conversion-in-scala.

Comment: Pattern matching, in this case, opens the "next can of worms": the matching (2.10.2) allows me to match a `List[_]`, but type erasure prevents a (strongly typed) match to `List[String]`; the compile issues a warning.

Answer (score 2):

`HList` to the rescue:

```
import shapeless._
import Nat._

val x = "item1" :: "item2" :: List("a,b,c") :: HNil   
val list_from_x = x(_2)
```

`list_from_x` has the type `List[String]`

See the shapeless [github page](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) for more info.

---

As other answers have mentioned, a `List` can only hold elements of a certain type. For example, a `List[String]` can only hold `String`s. If you put elements of mixed types into a `List`, then the parametrised type of the `List` will become the most specific type common to all the elements.

The most specific type common to `String` and `List` is `Any`. So in this example, `x` is of type `List[Any]`:

```
val x = List("item1" , "item2" , List ("a,b,c"))
```

`HList` can hold elements of different types and maintain each element's type.

Comment: this example is producing an error.                                           Multiple markers at this line(in method apply)(in method apply)(in method apply)(in method 
  apply)])at.Out cannot be applied to (Int)
 - Implicit conversions found: x => hlistOps(x)

Comment: Fixed. Tested in scala console.

Answer (score 0):

Scala compiler will simply say you got Objects (or may be Any) inside list x. That's why. You have to cast the 3rd element into a List in order to assign into a List variable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `List` is defined as `List[+A]` ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1)). Which means `List` takes a type parameter of co-variant type. (You can think of co-variance as type converting from narrow to broader. For ex: if `Dog` extends `Animal` and if you do `Animal a = new Dog()`, you have a Dog (narrow) converting to Animal (broader))

`x` is of type `List[Object]`. Doing

```
scala> val x = List ("item1" , "item2" , List ("a,b,c"))
x: List[Object] = List(item1, item2, List(a,b,c))

val list_from_x :List [String]= x(2)
```

is ultimately converting from `List[Object]` (broader) to `List[String]` (narrow). Which is contra-variant. Hence the compiler threw error because List is meant to be co-variant.

For ex: the below is completely valid. Thanks to co-variance:

```
scala> val x = List("hello")
x: List[String] = List(sdf)

scala> val o:List[Object] = x
o: List[Object] = List(sdf)
```

More about it [here](http://jatinpuri.com/2012/11/co-variance-contra-variance/) and [here](http://jatinpuri.com/2012/11/continuation/)